# How can I send /write data to the Industrial Motion Controller via HTTP in MATLAB?

Tags: json, matlab, http, controller, motion

I'm able to read a data from Motion Controller with HTTP in MATLAB .

Request code in MATLAB...

```
api = 'http://192.168.0.105';
 url = [api 'kas/plcvariables?variables=Velocity&format=text'];
 options = weboptions('ContentType', text);
 data = webread(url, options);
```

But, I can't write to the Motion Controller in MATLAB, with data format "text" or "json", it does not matter. How can I write to the Motion Controller?

Writing format in json

```
PUT http://198.51.100.0/kas/plcvariables?format=json { "MachineSpeed"
   : {"value" : "100.000000"}, " IntegerVar " : {"value" : "20"},
   “UntitledST.LocalVariable” : {"value" : "’SampleString’”} }
```

in text

```
    PUT http://198.51.100.0/kas/plcvariables?format=text
   MachineSpeed=100.000000,IntegerVar=20,UntitledST.LocalVariable=’SampleString’
```

I tried some code in Matlab, and the last one is below.

```
api = 'http://192.168.0.105';
 url = [api 'kas/plcvariables?'];
 ab = struct('value', '10000.00');
 data.V = {ab};
 options = webopitons('MediaType', 'application/json',
   'RequestMethod', 'POST', 'ContentType', 'json');
 response = webwrite(url, data, options);
```

But all of them gave the same errors that are below.

***Error using readContentFromWebService (line 45) The server returned the message: "Not Found" for URL, 'http://192.168.0.105/kas/plcvariables?' (with HTTP response code 404).***

I think I dont know the right URL address, Can you help me how I can write the right URL address for motion controller?

Comment: These may be errors in transcribing your code into this post, not in the original code, but in your first two code blocks you have some curly quote marks (`“`, `”`, `’`) where they probably need to be straight ones (`"`, `'`). Probably these are being wrongly auto-corrected by whatever text editor you're using. Also in your MATLAB code, `webopitons` looks like a typo for `weboptions`?

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think the issue is not curly quote marks because my first and fourth code are Matlab code and the others are  the format of writing some value to the motion controller that are written and explained in the user manual of motıon controller.

Comment: Hi,
I figure out where I'm wrong with the help of Martin (https://www.kollmorgen.com/en-us/developer-network/how-write-json-or-text-data-variables-c/). I share code for anybody who may need this with link above.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution! Please consider writing this up into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out where I'm wrong with the help of Martin (kollmorgen.com/en-us/developer-network/…). I share code for anybody who may need this with link above and code as below

```
int main() {
    CURLcode ret;
    CURL *curl_easy_handle;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    std::string jsonstr = "{\"Position\" : {\"value\" : \"4000\"}}";

    struct curl_slist *headers;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");        
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8");

    curl_easy_handle = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl_easy_handle == NULL) {
        return 128;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.105/kas/plcvariables?format=json");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonstr.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcrp/0.1");

    ret = curl_easy_perform(curl_easy_handle);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_easy_handle);
    curl_global_cleanup();        
    curl_easy_handle = NULL;

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    headers = NULL;
}
```